# Loading existing datasets into empty geodatabase (with schema) in ModelBuilder with iterator and append?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, iterator, append

I'd like to load existing feature classes within a dataset in one geodatabase into a new, empty geodatabase with schema already set up.  Both geodatabases, the one containing the data and the one containing the schema are .mdb and were acquired from the ESRI page for downloading data models . This is step 4 of a process. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/using-arcgis-data-model-designs.htm

I have tried unsuccessfully to load the data using the append and iterator in ModelBuilder.  I have no experience with Python, but feel that somehow this could be accomplished through ModelBuilder. I've combed through the iterator tool information to no avail.

What are non-programmer options for loading this data?
[image: Last attempt to build model.]

Comment: I faced a similar problem a a few months ago. It turned out to be easier to learn python basics rather than use the model builder. arcpy (the GIS python module) is well documented so if you search exact things you need to do it is relatively easy to figure out. Sorry I can't be of help with ModelBuilder.

Comment: Can you update your question and show us a screen shot of your model?